# Matlab : Minimum of matrix

Tags: matlab

I need to find the minimum of an entire matrix and it's 'coordinates'.
In a matrix like

```
matrix = 8 7 6 5  
         4 3 2 1
```

The minimum would be 1 at (2, 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can very simply be done by using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), where you would use the two output version of it.  So what you want to do is search for those row and column locations in your matrix that match the minimum value in your matrix.

Therefore:

```
[row, col] = find(matrix == min(matrix(:)));
```

`row` and `col` would contain the row and column locations of `matrix` that are equal to this minimum value.  Note that I had to unroll the matrix into a vector by doing `matrix(:)`.  The reason why is because if you were to use `min` on a matrix, it would by default give you the minimum along each column.  Because you want to find the minimum over the entire matrix, you would convert this into a single vector, then find the minimum along the entire vector.

Take note that this will return **all** row and column locations that match the minimum, so it would actually give `row` and `col` as `N x 1` column vectors, where `N` is the total amount of elements in `matrix` that equal the minimum.

If you only want **one** match, simply append a 1 as the second parameter to `find`:

```
[row, col] = find(matrix == min(matrix(:)), 1);
```

Comment: I was complicating.. Thank you!

Comment: @Ain - Made some small typos.  I was basically missing a bracket for each line of code, but I'm sure you figured that out by now!

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which will work for a tensor of any number of dimensions, is to use `min` with linear indexing, then use `ind2sub` to recover the exact indices, if required.

```
[~, nIndex] = min(matrix(:));
[nIndex1, nIndex2, nIndex3, ...] = ind2sub(size(matrix), nIndex);
```

Comment: I just tried this code.  `ind2subs` does not exist on my MATLAB distribution.  I also searched on the MATLAB docs for this function and it doesn't exist.  Retracting my vote.  Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, should have been `ind2sub`.