# How can I find the minima of a 3D matrix in a given dimension?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, min

So I want to take the minimum of a 3D matrix, but I want to be able to chose in which dimension I want to take the minimum. For example, if I have a random 2x3x4 matrix. I want the minimum in the z direction (i.e. 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension).

```
M = rand(2, 3, 4)
MinMatrix = function(M, direction)
```

With direction I mean per row, per column, or per z direction. Now say I want the minimum in the z direction, so the function should give me the `MinMatrix` which is 2x3 in dimension and gives me the minima of the 4 numbers in the z direction:

```
Min1  Min2  Min3
Min4  Min5  Min6
```

This is the code I tried just to get the minimum, without the direction part yet:

```
function [MinMatrix] = functionname(M)
  MinMatrix = min(M(:, :, 1:4));
end
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216606/matlab-minimum-of-matrix), along with [a similar question on The MathWorks website](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/52341-minimum-of-a-3d-matrix), but that involves reshaping the original matrix which I would like to avoid and you have to change the code to change the dimension. It's unclear from those questions how I can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [dimension argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#bua94lg-1-dim) for the [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function:

```
MinMatrix = min(M, [], 3);  % Minimum along the 3rd dimension
```

Note that, in this case, you have to pass an empty matrix for the second argument (an easy thing to forget when working with `min` and `max`).